# Alternate Column Position (Left & Right)

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have a list of post on a WordPress website that has an excerpt and an image. Each on in a column. One floated left, one floated right.

What I want to achieve is to alternate each post so that the first has a left aligned image, and right aligned text; then the second has a right aligned image and left aligned text, and then the next, left aligned image, right aligned text. 
Perhaps there is a PhP or JS/Jquery way of doing this?

*Please see image so you can see what I mean.

There is also a basic HTML/CSS JSFiddle here: jsfiddle.net/huwrowlands/7WGTm/

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS3 Pseudo (odd,even)**

Using the new pseudo class `:nth-child(odd)` or `:nth-child(even)` it's very easy.

```
.hp-module {
 width: 100%;
}
.col{
 width: 46%;
 padding: 2%;
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
}
.hp-module:nth-child(odd)>div{
 float:left;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/7WGTm/3/

Answer (score 3):

**Now try to this**

Used to **pseudo-classes** `:nth-child(even)` in your css **define** this in **parents div** as like this

```
.hp-module:nth-child(even) > .col:first-child{
    float:right;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7WGTm/2/)**

more about **[nth-child](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)**